# Change order of fragments

Tags: android, fragment

I am using `FragmentManager` to dynamically add fragments to an activity. How can I add a new fragment before another one instead of just at the end without having to redo the entire set of fragments?

For example, on the activity there are three fragments shown vertically like this:
`FragA`
`FragB`
`FragC`

When I add a fourth fragment ***`NewFragD`*** they should now be arranged like this:
`FragA`
***`NewFragD`***
`FragB`
`FragC`

Comment: Do you mean replacing a fragment in a certain container?

Comment: I think he means inserting a fragment into an arbitrary position of the backstack without having to pop everything off first.

Comment: Sorry I guess that wasn't very clear. I edited my example so hopefully it makes more sense now. All the fragments are visible on the activity, but when I add a new one I don't want it to appear after all of the ones I already have.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if (position == 0) return new frg1();
    else if (position == 1) if (newFragment)return new Mapfrag2(); else return frg2()
    else if (position == 2) return new frg3(); 
   else return new frg1();
}
```

Comment: Don't guess in your answers. Either ask a question in a *comment*, or provide an answer in the *answer*.

Comment: this works for me,i didn't anderstand very well what he needs; i try to help

Comment: Getting a specific fragment isn't the problem. What I need is to be able to insert a new one between existing fragments.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar issue and I don't think it's possible to reorder fragments already committed.

The way I fixed this issue that I found to be better than clearing and re-adding the fragments in the right order is to have all the potential fragments added in the correct order and then show/hide when they are ready to be displayed.

So in your example, you would initially have:

```
transaction.add(FragA)
transaction.add(FragD)
transaction.add(FragB)
transaction.add(FragC)
```

and then this line before committing the transaction

```
transaction.hide(FragD)
```

and when it's time to show the frag you would create another transaction and add this line

```
transaction.show(FragD)
```

This is better since all the fragments wouldn't have to go through the lifecycle again. I've found that using show/hide instead of trying to add a fragment to the transaction results in clearer and more performant code.

This will only work if you have a fixed order for all potential fragments, if you need to dynamically change the order then you would resort to clearing and adding fragments in the proper order each time you need to update it.